# Importing data from RDBMS using sqoop to hive

Tags: hive, sqoop, rdbms

I was trying to import data from RDBMS using sqoop into hive but getting below error :

```
premature end of file hive-site.xml
```

Comment: Could you please add in your sqoop command and entire error here?

Comment: Looks like your hive-site.xml can have syntax error.

Comment: hive-site.xml dose not balanced the tag. ensure that all the opened tags are closed properly.